# the input stream is not a valid binary format. TCP error c#

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, network-programming

I have been working on a file sharing application that chunks a file of any size, serializes each chunk and sends it orderly using a TCP connection. But I have a problem when receiving between two systems, the error says "the input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 0D-0A-00-01-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-01-00-00-00-00-00 "  but the sender sends the appropriate number of bytes. Is it because I am using the beginRead and beginWrite methods of networkstream or what?. Please what am i doing wrong? 
My Client Code.

```
public void SendMessage(string path)
   {
        NetworkStream file = new NetworkStream(client);

        try {
            foreach (Chunk item in ChunkAlgorithm.ReadChunk(path))
            {

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BinaryFormatter serialize = new BinaryFormatter();
                    serialize.Serialize(stream, item);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    SentBytes = stream.ToArray();
                    file.BeginWrite(SentBytes, 0, SentBytes.Length, MessageSentCallBack, null);
                    //Console.WriteLine($"sent: {SentBytes.Length} bytes");
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done sending bytes");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR OCURRED: {ex.Message}");
        }
      //client.BeginSend(empty, 0, 0, 0, MessageSentCallBack, null);

    }
```

My Server Code.

```
      public void StartReceiving()
    {


            file.BeginRead(receivingBytes, 0, receivingBytes.Length, ReceivedCallBack,null);

    }

    private void ReceivedCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try {
            string savepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test1.mp4");


            int receivedLength = file.EndRead(ar);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(receivingBytes))
            {

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Chunk ReceivedChunk = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Chunk;

                if (ReceivedChunk.LastChunk)
                {
                    ChunkList.Add(ReceivedChunk);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received Chunk: {ReceivedChunk.chunkCount} of {receivedLength} bytes");
                    couple(ChunkList, savepath);
                }
                else
                {
                    ChunkList.Add(ReceivedChunk);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received Chunk: {ReceivedChunk.chunkCount} of {receivedLength} bytes");
                }

            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            StartReceiving();

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR OCURRED: {ex.Message}");
        }

    }

    private static void couple(List<Chunk> ChunkList,string savepath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Coupling...");
        ChunkAlgorithm.couple(ChunkList, savepath);
        Console.WriteLine("Coupling Done...");
        Console.WriteLine("Received All Data...");
    }
```

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` format is undocumented and proprietary.  What if you send something readable like a JSON string instead?

Comment: What do you mean?... I am serialising the content of a part of the  file  and sending it.

Comment: Right, and the file has undocumented format so it's hard to see where things goes wrong.  Testing with a readable, documented format may make debugging easier.

Comment: Okay I get your point, but when debugging I notice that the sender sends the actual amount of bytes but the receiver does not receive the actual amount of bytes at different points each time I run it. So I am thinking it's a problem with concurrency.

Comment: Ah - I didn't see anything in your question stating that fewer bytes were received, just that *the input stream is not a valid binary format*, which could be due to many different things such as a difference in endianness or lack of type identity between the sending & receiving systems.  `BinaryFormatter` streams are "fussy" and are not guaranteed to be compatible between computers using different DLL versions or architectures.  You might want to [edit] your question to give a simpler example that cuts out the `BinaryFormatter` uncertainty.